# IIS executes "malicious.asp;.txt" as ASP file. What the?

Tags: asp.net, iis, hacking, server-side-scripting

I investigated a situation where 300+ websites hosted on an IIS server were pwned by a hacker. Investigation led me to a text file that contained malicious ASP-classic code. The file was named `dz.asp;.txt` and I just realized that IIS happily executed this file without complaining.

So my question is: is this behavior normal? Shouldn't IIS treat this file as a `.txt` file instead of `.asp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It became known in 2009 that IIS had a vulnerability in that it determined filetype by the part of the filename preceeding a semicolon if there was one in the name.

See [this NIST description](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2009-4444) for more details.

Comment: Did they ever fix it?

Comment: This is a good example of why whitelists/blacklists just aren't good enough. You should always store user-uploaded data outside of the docroot and use a passthrough script to display it back to the user.

Comment: mgkrebbs - over at Area 51, you signed up as a follower on the Genealogy Q&A proposal. http://bit.ly/U3vnDX  We're now in Commitment Phase. It would really help the proposal get to Beta if you could "Commit". Sorry to add this comment here, but it was the only way I could see to contact you.